# Is there any proper way to escape array without brackets in MeekroDB?

Tags: php, mysql, meekro

I want to write query like this in MeekroDB:

```
SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE `id` IN (3,1,2) ORDER BY FIELD (`id`,3,1,2)
```

And I expect it to work like this in meekro:

```
$possible_ids = array(1,2,3);
DB::query('SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE `id` IN %ld0 ORDER BY FIELD (`id`,%ld0)', $possible_ids);
```

But it get this:

```
SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE `id` IN (3,1,2) ORDER BY FIELD (`id`,(3,1,2))
```

Is there any way to avoid this brackets here?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one :

```
$possible_ids = implode(',', array(1, 2, 3));
//echo "SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE `id` IN %ld0 ORDER BY FIELD (`id`,%ld0)', $possible_ids";

DB::query('SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE `id` IN %ld0 ORDER BY FIELD (`id`,%ld0)', $possible_ids);
```

also you can check with echo query.
try it's working fine.

Comment: Yeah, back then I used exactly this solution, but it's vulnerable to sql injections if used with user-provided data and I had to validate that data first.